# Why does my process list show multiple threads when running aiohttp?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm currently using aiohttp in one of my projects which uses asyncio. After searching for reasons why I'm getting a high amount of memory usage I detected that aiohttp seem to create threads in the background.

I have broken down my code to this minimal code which shows my problem.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def test1(link, session):
    async with session.get(
        link,
    ) as r:
        print(r.status)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def test():
    async with ClientSession(
        cookie_jar=aiohttp.DummyCookieJar(),
) as session:
        await asyncio.gather(test1("https://google.com", session))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(test())
loop.close()
```

When running this with `ps -e -T |grep python3` I get the following output, which is odd because it looks like it created a thread:

```
 160304  160304 pts/5    00:00:00 python3
 160304  160306 pts/5    00:00:00 python3
```

If I change the asyncio.gather to use one more test1 function and run the ps command again I get three threads instead:

```
 160414  160414 pts/5    00:00:00 python3
 160414  160416 pts/5    00:00:00 python3
 160414  160417 pts/5    00:00:00 python3
```

This looks very problematic because my assumption was that aiohttp uses an event loop in a single thread, this is why I have used `ThreadPoolExecutor` to launch a specified amount of threads at the start of the program. If aiohttp creates a new thread for every session.get request then the amount of threads is possibly X specified threads * the current running HTTP requests.

For more context I'm using:

- Python 3.8.10
- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

The purpose of my main program is to save the HTML of X amount of domains as quickly as possible. The current architecture is using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to spin up Y amount of threads and using it throughout the application life, then every thread sends Z amount of HTTP requests simultaneously using session.get and asyncio.gather. Is this the wrong approach and should I use another Python library instead of aiohttp? Is threading in combination with event loops redundant?

I have searched around on the web and I have not found an answer to this question, so I'm humbly asking the community for any smart input.

Comment: Are you somehow expecting one thread to execute two different calls to `sleep` at the same time?

Comment: I changed the endpoints to localhost and created a file called sleep.php with sleep(10); as the only line of code now and see that asyncio does not create more threads. I was only adding asyncio.sleep to demonstrate the issue, but it looks like the issue was in my programming logic when demonstrating this. My assumption was that asyncio will never create more threads, but will in the worst case block. Perhaps this is the reason why my actual program is having issues. Are you aware of if it's possible to prevent asyncio to block instead of creating more threads?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you intend to call `sleep` twice at the same time, you will need two threads. One thread has to sleep -- without another thread, how will you keep processing asynchronous I/Os that complete while that thread is sleeping?

Comment: The issue isn't the sleeping part, I'm only using sleep so I got enough time to run ps -e -T |grep python3 and check how many threads is being ran. The issue is that asyncio is creating threads when I call session.get, my assumption was that asyncio is a single threaded event loop.

Comment: It looks like I was able to mitigate this problem by using a Semaphore from the asyncio package, it feels like a bit of a shortcut though.

Answer (score 3):

asyncio always has at least one thread pool under the hood with `min(32, (os.cpu_count() or 1) + 4)` threads started.

The pool is used by `asyncio` for DNS lookup internally.

Moreover, even if you setup `aiohttp` to use `aiodns` for DNS resolving, the default asyncio pool still exists (while does nothing).

In turn, `aiohttp` uses the default thread pool for some operations, mostly for local file handling.

For example, `await session.post(url, data=open('filename', 'rb'))` reads the file chunks for sending in threads; it helps to avoid long blocking calls.